# ASP.NET generated excel file has different format than extension

Tags: asp.net, excel, xmlwriter

I have a web application made in old asp.net 2.0. I need to generate excel file with specific formated table (the best way if I can load the template and only put data in code behind). To do this I'm trying to use this library CarlosAg.ExcelXmlWriter:
http://www.carlosag.net/tools/excelxmlwriter/sample

And the final file is generated very well, but when I'm trying to open it in MS Excel warning popup appear  with information that **file has different format than the extension** (xls). And also question if I want to open it if I trust the source of file. When I click yes, the file opened properly. On the other pc with different version of Excel, there's also warning, but different - file is broken and cannot be opened, the same in mobile (no possibility to open). What is interesting - I can open that file properly without any warnings in different office program, ex. WPS Office.
So I make two steps back and try to open just simple file generated by the sample of Carlos library and effect is the same. Is there any chance to "fix" the file in code behind so MS Excel could also open it properly without any warnings?

```
    Dim book As Workbook = New Workbook()
    Dim sheet As Worksheet = book.Worksheets.Add("Sample")
    Dim row As WorksheetRow = sheet.Table.Rows.Add()
    row.Cells.Add("Hello World")
    book.Save("D:\Folder\test.xls")
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to give the file extension xlsx.

The older xls is in fact the legacy (closed) binary format of office files.

However, since office 2007, Microsoft has adopted a open xml format for ALL office documents (well, ok, outlook pst, and MS-Access are exceptions). In fact, if you take any office document (word, power-point, excel) etc., try renaming the xlsx document as a zip file. You find that you can now open the zip archive, and you can see/look at and even modify the xml in that document.

(do try this rename as a zip file for fun and giggles - you see how you actually don't even need any 3rd party tools to open, play with, and mess with the content in the zip archive (so, all office documents are in fact a simple zip archive!!!).

So, newer office file formats are in fact xml markup - and you can modify it!!

Anyway, without a doubt that library you are using thus uses the above feature/fact of office documents now being xml formatted and NOT a propriety Microsoft binary format - you can in fact modify such documents now on ANY computer that is able to open a zip file, and modify text files.

As a result, you are giving the document name a legacy binary file name (xls), but opening a xml formatted file (plain text), and thus Excel is detecting this fact/issue. So, you need to give that document the open office xml format extension (xlsx).

Comment: That's a nice piece of mystery you described :) I changed file extension to xlsx (for ex. the last line in the sample code above), and unfotunately file cannot be opened in Excel, the warning appear: _Excel cannot open the file test.xlsx because the file format or file extension is not valid. Verify that the file has not been corrupted and that the file extension matches the format of the file._  And again there's no problem to open it in other office tools (like WPS), only this MS Excel..

Comment: I make a test by changing extension from xslx to zip, and I look into the structure inside. I found sharedStrings.xml which contains just data from cells. That's a good news ;) So I can prepared template with formated cells in Excel and uploaded to server as 'unzipped' folder and then just change data in one xml file. The challenge could be to zip all parts of the folder into one part. Probably it's not possible with standard libraries, so I need to dig it for some _zip library_ or something similar.

Comment: Well, the external library CarlosAg.ExcelXmlWriter does exactly what you suggest. So, perhaps you continue to use that library, and use your base file template idea, add to it, and then it should work? In other words, you can quite well go down your idea/road, and modify the xml direct, but the whole idea of CarlosAg.ExcelXmlWriter is to do all that work for you.  so consider both - (your blank pre-made template), and then use that CarlosAg.ExcelXmlWriter to do the heavy lifting parts.

Comment: I made lot of work with CarlosAg.ExcelXmlWriter and I really want to continue but this library still gives me warning that _file has different format than the extension_. Also when I am do open worbook function in code (Workbook.Open("MyTemplate") it's opening only .xls version, with .xlsx it gives me an error like _Data at the root level is invalid. Line 1, position 1._ Even if I open template as .xls and save as .xlsx, still gives me warning about different format.

Comment: So I think maybe I should drop the CarlosAg.ExcelXmlWriter library, makes two steps back, and try to use ClosedXML or something else, or so it manualy by using template as unpacked files and replace data only in sharedStrings.xml. But in that case I need external library for pack files into zip anyway, because I don't see zip function in original asp.net functions (and finally change extension to xlsx and push to client).

Comment: Well, I actually suggest to use that Excel writer library. It should work. It not at a all clear why the resulting xlxs file does not work. As noted, you might create a blank xlxs file in Excel, and then try/use modify that template - see if that works. It is up to you, but I would think using a that library going to be boatloads less work then cooking up your own code. .net around 4.5 includes zip file support.

Comment: Story finished with success - I used Free Spire XLS library instead of CarlosAg (probably too old for nowadays) and **xlsx** files works without any warnings. This library in free version has limitarions, but it's enough for now. Thanks for your tips and patience :)